# replace specific value in pandas dataframes using the mean between 10 previous and next values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

Let's say I have the following dataframe

```
df.Consumption

0        16.208
1        11.193
2         9.845
3         9.348
4         9.091
          ...  
19611     0.000
19612     0.000
19613     0.000
19614     0.000
19615     0.000
Name: Consumption, Length: 19616, dtype: float64
```

I want to replace the 0 values with the mean of the 10 previous and next values that are not 0.00

What is a good way to do it? I was thinking about using the replace and interpolate methods but I can't see how to write it efficiently

Comment: How are the numbers of previous and next values are distributed? Should we have 5 each for non-zero previous and next numbers or should we have the closest possible previous and next non-zero values with previous prioritized?

Comment: @taxevader   yes, that would be the most logical way to do it. I also think that it should be equally distributed and if there are not enough values (if we are at the start or at the end for example we select more from the other side), but anyway that I guess is a detail. I just want to see if there's a way to do it without needing a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with `center=True` together with [`Rolling.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) to get the mean of previous and next values.

Replace `0` by `NaN` if you want to exclude `0` from the mean calculation.

Set `center=True` so that the rolling windows look for both previous and next entries.

Finally, set those entries with value `0` with the mean values by using `.loc`, as follows:

```
n = 10     # check previous and next 10 entries

# rolling window size is (2n + 1)
Consumption_mean = (df['Consumption'].replace(0, np.nan)
                                     .rolling(n * 2 + 1, min_periods=1, center=True)
                                     .mean())

df.loc[df['Consumption'] == 0, 'Consumption'] = Consumption_mean
```

**Demo**

Using smaller window size `n = 3` to demonstrate:

```
df


    Consumption
0        16.208
1        11.193
2         9.845
3         9.348
4         9.091
5         8.010
6         0.000              <====   target entry
7         7.100
8         0.000              <====   target entry
9         6.800
10        6.500
11        6.300
12        5.900
13        5.800
14        5.600

#n = 10     # check previous and next 10 entries
n = 3     # smaller window size for demo

# rolling window size is (2n + 1)
Consumption_mean = (df['Consumption'].replace(0, np.nan)
                                     .rolling(n * 2 + 1, min_periods=1, center=True)
                                     .mean())

# Update into a new column `Consumption_New` for demo purpose
df['Consumption_New'] = df['Consumption']    
df.loc[df['Consumption'] == 0, 'Consumption_New'] = Consumption_mean
```

**Demo Result:**

```
print(df)

    Consumption  Consumption_New
0        16.208          16.2080
1        11.193          11.1930
2         9.845           9.8450
3         9.348           9.3480
4         9.091           9.0910
5         8.010           8.0100
6         0.000           8.0698   # 8.0698 = (9.348 + 9.091 + 8.01 + 7.1 + 6.8) / 5 with skipping 0.000 between 7.100 and 6.800
7         7.100           7.1000
8         0.000           6.9420   # 6.942 = (8.01 + 7.1 + 6.8 + 6.5 + 6.3) / 5 with skipping 0.000 between 8.010 and 7.100
9         6.800           6.8000
10        6.500           6.5000
11        6.300           6.3000
12        5.900           5.9000
13        5.800           5.8000
14        5.600           5.6000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will verify it as the answered solution. However, I have a question. Let say I have a streak of 10 nans, if I choose a window of 7 the ones in the center will only have a mean of nans. is there a way to count the rows only with non-Nans values?

Comment: @lalaland  Actually, if you want to count the rows only with non-Nans values, the most clear cut way is to drop the rows with `NaN` before processing.  e.g. by using [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to drop the `NaN` rows before processing.

Comment: but the resulting data frame would not have the same size and I would not be able to replace it with the computed mean, no?

Comment: @lalaland You can drop the `Nan` rows right before all steps here so that the means calculation and the replacement step are based on the same dropped dataframe such that the data are consistent and correctly aligned.

Comment: @lalaland  or did you mean the `NaN` values are the originally 0 values in the column ?   If you mean this, then you were checking whether there's a way for a window size of 7 to look at beyond the window size to look at eg. >=11 entries?   Since our window size cannot be dynamically stretched, it is not possible.  However, if you just don't want to get results with `NaN` entries in this case for these originally 0 values, you can fill out these `NaN` values back to 0 eg. by `.fillna(0)`. The result is reasonable since the 0 values just cannot be filled out by within the range of window size.

Comment: Yes, I meant the second option. So there's no way to dynamically change the size of the window? Thanks for answering. I appreciate it

Comment: @lalaland Right, there's no way to dynamically change the size of the window.  Maybe unless you write a custom function to do that rather than using built-in functions.  But then the processing will be very slow, especially for large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you pretty close.  It takes advantage of the null values not being counted in the mean, so you can replace zero with nan and then just loop through.

I'm not sure of a better way to do with without a row-wise apply.

Something tells me that doing an actual loop, where you update the df each iteration will give you slightly different results, as you will be imputing nulls as you go, which will make the prior 10 results always have a value.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Consumption':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]})
df.replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
df.update(df.apply(lambda x:np.mean(df.Consumption.iloc[max(x.name-10,0):]), axis=1).to_frame('Consumption'),overwrite=False)
```

Output

```
Consumption
0   1.000000
1   1.000000
2   1.000000
3   1.000000
4   1.000000
5   1.000000
6   1.000000
7   1.000000
8   1.000000
9   1.526316
10  2.000000
11  2.000000
12  2.000000
13  2.000000
14  2.000000
15  2.000000
16  2.000000
17  2.000000
18  2.000000
19  2.000000
```